# What is the best way to trim all possible whitespace characters PLUS custom characters from the beginning of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, trim

In C#, I want to Trim() both ends of a string of all possible types of whitespace characters (as defined by .IsWhitespace), plus trim the beginning of the string to ALSO remove any character from a custom list in a char[] array, occurring before regular alphanumeric characters.  So the string should end up such that the first character is not any whitespace and is not one of the characters in my custom list.  (However, the string may, of course include whitespace or characters in my list AFTER the first character.)

I want to iterate through the string only one time to do all of this, because there is a large list of strings to trim.

The following does not work (see more comment below the code snippet).

```
    static class TrimmerExtension
    {
        private const string _prefixCharsToTrimAsString = "~`$|-_";
        private static readonly char[] _prefixCharsToTrim;

        // static ctor
        static TrimmerExtension()
        {
            _prefixCharsToTrim = _prefixCharsToTrimAsString.ToCharArray();
        }

        public static string TrimWhitespaceAndPrefixes(this string s)
        {
            return s.Trim().TrimStart(_prefixCharsToTrim).TrimStart();
        }
    }
```

The above does not work, because:

1. it calls different versions of Trim several times, thus iterating through the string several times.  (So the above is inefficient);
2. it does not completely trim all whitespaces and special characters from the beginning if there are whitespace characters between other characters to be trimmed; for example, if the string contains "  $  ~ Something  ", the extension method would return "~ Something", but the first two characters still need to be removed.  (So the above code is incorrect.)

Does C# or .NET provide an efficient way to do this (in terms of both performance and source code simplicity)?  Alternatively, is there a class or library that defines a constant character (or string) array of all possible whitespace characters that the Trim() function would remove from a string, so I can add it to the list of my special prefix characters to be removed?

If this specific question is already answered, please post a link to the question and answer(s).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect more whitespace than CR, LF, TAB, SPACE? Why not add them explicitly to the trim list?

Comment: Efficiency isn't really an issue if you call `Trim` once with *all* the characters you need trimmed. If you need something allocation-free because the trimmed value is a work in progress, use `Span`s.

Comment: @Hans Kesting: The string is suppled from an external source over which I nave no control. So although I would not normally expect it to contain whitespace characters other than, say TAB or SPACE, I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: You could write a small program that runs through all char values and prints the codes of all whitespaces. Let's hope there are no surrogate pairs that are whitespace

Comment: @madreflection "all characters [that need to be] trimmed".  Right, but that is the question.  Just how do I include all whitespace characters that Trim would normally remove?  There is no definitive list that I can find anywhere; i.e. either a char[] array or string definition including all whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there's no easy way as `string.Trim()` internally uses two distinct methods for that.

TrimWhiteSpaceHelper for whitespaces:

```
    private string TrimWhiteSpaceHelper(TrimType trimType)
    {
        // end will point to the first non-trimmed character on the right.
        // start will point to the first non-trimmed character on the left.
        int end = Length - 1;
        int start = 0;

        // Trim specified characters.
        if ((trimType & TrimType.Head) != 0)
        {
            for (start = 0; start < Length; start++)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(this[start]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((trimType & TrimType.Tail) != 0)
        {
            for (end = Length - 1; end >= start; end--)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(this[end]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return CreateTrimmedString(start, end);
    }
```

and TrimHelper for custom chars:

```
private unsafe string TrimHelper(char* trimChars, int trimCharsLength, TrimType trimType)
    {
        Debug.Assert(trimChars != null);
        Debug.Assert(trimCharsLength > 0);

        // end will point to the first non-trimmed character on the right.
        // start will point to the first non-trimmed character on the left.
        int end = Length - 1;
        int start = 0;

        // Trim specified characters.
        if ((trimType & TrimType.Head) != 0)
        {
            for (start = 0; start < Length; start++)
            {
                int i = 0;
                char ch = this[start];
                for (i = 0; i < trimCharsLength; i++)
                {
                    if (trimChars[i] == ch)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == trimCharsLength)
                {
                    // The character is not in trimChars, so stop trimming.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((trimType & TrimType.Tail) != 0)
        {
            for (end = Length - 1; end >= start; end--)
            {
                int i = 0;
                char ch = this[end];
                for (i = 0; i < trimCharsLength; i++)
                {
                    if (trimChars[i] == ch)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == trimCharsLength)
                {
                    // The character is not in trimChars, so stop trimming.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return CreateTrimmedString(start, end);
    }
```

Combining them could look like that:

```
public static class TrimmerExtension
{
    public static string TrimWhitespaceAndPrefixes(this string str, params char[] trimChars)
    {
        var trimCharsLength = trimChars.Length;
        int start;
        for (start = 0; start < str.Length; start++)
        {
            var ch = str[start];
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < trimCharsLength; i++)
                {
                    if (trimChars[i] == ch)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i == trimCharsLength)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return str[start..];
    }
}
```

If performance is not very important, I suggest to use regular expressions or a shorthand version from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133168/2770274

Comment: Thank you, @Adassko.  I guess I do have to write a custom method to iterate through the string, then, and it looks like this answer (or something like it) is the way to go.  As I indicated in my question, performance MAY be an issue because the source list of strings to process can possibly get rather large.

Comment: in this case I suggest also to return `ReadOnlySpan<>` instead of a string, it could give a big performance boost if you further process those strings

Comment: I have never heard of Span<> before so never used it.  I shall look into that.  Thanks!.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do it by hand?

```
public static string MySpecialTrim(string str, char[] trimChars)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) && !trimChars.Contains(ch))              
            return str.Substring(i);
    }
    return str;
}
```

That way you control what characters get trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `TrimStart()`.
- It will remove all the leading white-space characters from the current string.
- You can also pass character array which you want to remove from the leading of string.
- for example you wat to remove space $ and percent from leading of string you can do as below?

```cs
string input = "$%Hello World";

char[] trimChars = {' ', '$', '%'};

string output = input.TrimStart(trimChars);

Console.WriteLine(output); // Output: "Hello World"
```

- To remove from end of string you can use `TrimEnd()`.
- **For more information regarding [TrimStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-8.0) and [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-8.0).**

Comment: Yes, they know they can use `TrimStart`, but they can't, as explained in their question underneath their code.

Comment: My understanding is that:

char[] trimChars = {' ', '$', '%'};

string output = input.TrimStart(trimChars);

would only remove the specified characters and the only whitespace character that would be removed is just the space character itself.. I believe that Trim() removes a whole plethora of many different types of whitespace characters, and I would like them ALL to be removed from the start of the string.